# Right Approach to Call Web Service(API) from Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I have an activity which has a fragment and a dialog. And I am calling an API from the fragment in the onCreateView method. And when I am on the fragment and opens the dialog then fragment again hits the API. I want to prevent it.I want that my app do not hit when I am opening a dialog.

// code

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);

        callApi()

         }
```

Comment: call your api in onViewCreated

Comment: when i get back to the frag from another activity, the api is called again. i dont want that.  any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

call your api in `onViewCreated` like this.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

           callApi();  //here call your function.


    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work with bottom navigation. Any idea?

Comment: @Mac_Play did you solve this I'm facing the same issue right now its call again and again